# AngularJS view not updated from scope tied to factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Take a look at the code sample provided below.

Click on the bold hello text. As you can see the scope is updated from the factory, scope.myFactory.str is appended to the directive. However, the view is not. I'm trying to use scope.apply() to update the view, but it is not working. So I'm expecting the bold text to update. Note that the factory's data can be changed from anywhere, so I can't simply call scope.$apply() on the click event.

```js
angular.module('myModule', []) 

.factory('myFactory', function($http, $window){
    return { str:'hello' };
})

.directive('mydir', ['$timeout', 'myFactory', function ($timeout, myFactory) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        template:'<div><b>{{myf.str}}</b>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.myf = myFactory;
          
         scope.$watch('scope.myf', function(n, o) {
           scope.$apply();
            
          });
          
             elem.bind('click', function(){
               myFactory.str += '1';
               elem.append(scope.myf.str);
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

```html
<html ng-app='myModule'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<mydir></mydir>
```

Comment: your code trow the Error: error:inprog
Action Already In Progress. maybe remove $apply

Comment: What is your expected behavior? Based on the code snippet it appears to be working fine. Your `scope.$watch` call is incorrect (the argument should just be `myf`, and `$.apply` should not be used) but it's also redundant.

Comment: @sgress454 The myf.str is not updated in the view. When you click at hello, you can see that scope.myf.str is updated, but not rendered in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you're changing the scope in your `click` event, but that handler doesn't automatically *apply* the scope changes.  Moving the `scope.$apply()` to the click handler does the trick.  You also have to get rid of the `scope.$watch`; it's redundant in this context and will lead to either a digest error or an infinite loop.

I also removed the `elem.append` so that you can more cleanly see the effect of changing the scope.

```js
angular.module('myModule', []) 

.factory('myFactory', function($http, $window){
    return { str:'hello' };
})

.directive('mydir', ['$timeout', 'myFactory', function ($timeout, myFactory) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        template:'<div><b>{{myf.str}}</b>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.myf = myFactory;
                        
             elem.bind('click', function(){
               myFactory.str += '1';
               scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

```html
<html ng-app='myModule'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<mydir></mydir>
```

Comment: Thanks, in order to simplify the example the service is changed from the directive. But in my real app I am changing the factory from many other places. So this works in this context, but not in the real app.

Comment: Ok.  Well, I'm not sure how good of an answer you're gonna get if your example doesn't really reflect your app, but the most important point with *your* example is that you have to do `scope.$apply` in the click handler.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to simplify it in order show in a short example. The services data can be changed from anywhere by anyone that inject it. So from these places I cannot access the scope of the directive.

Comment: It seem's I can call scope.$apply() on any scope. Thanks :)